# Rails - storing a date when the day is optional

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm collecting a date to store in the database but have to account for the fact that the user may not know the exact date. I want to offer the option to only enter the month and year. What would be the best way to store these values on the database?

If I use a Date object without the day and then store it as a date in the database then it defaults to the 1st of the month, which would be inaccurate. I had the idea of potentially storing the day, month and year separately as integers and then having a method on the model that returned a Date object and whether or not the day was accurate (ie had been inputted by the user and not just defaulted by the system).

It seems a little messy though, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can store a date in one column and precision in other, eg "2017-03-28","day" and "2017-03-01", "month", so you would distinct it from exact date "2017-03-01", "day"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple solutions available. Choose one which serves your use-cases the best:

**1. Individual date-part fields**

You've already experimented with this idea. It seems something like this:

```
create table t(
  year  int,
  month int,
  day   int
)
```

A month of `2017-03` could be represented with `(2017, 3, NULL)`.

Note that all fields are `NULL`-able. You can make `year NOT NULL` if you want to some information at least.

With this model, you must use client logic to construct some kind of date-like object for further use.

The big disadvantage of this model is that it is hard to index. You could index f.ex. `make_date(year, coalesce(month, 1), coalesce(day, 1))` but using it in queries is rather inconvenient. Also, to disallow some value compositions, which make no sense (f.ex. given a year and a day, but not a month), you should add a (really long) `CHECK` constraint too, f.ex.

```
CHECK (CASE
  WHEN year IS NULL THEN month IS NULL AND day IS NULL
  ELSE CASE WHEN month IS NULL THEN day IS NULL END
END)
```

**2. Sample date and precision**

```
create table t(
  sample_date      date,
  sample_precision date_precision -- enum of f.ex. 'year', 'month', 'day'
)
```

A month of `2017-03` could be represented with `('2017-03-28', 'month')`.

This doesn't require long `CHECK` constraints, but it is fairly hard to select by dates if `sample_date` is truly just a sample (f.ex. when the whole month of `2017-03` should be represented in a row, a sample date could even be `2017-03-28`). When you use the first date as `sample_date` (from the values it can take, based on `sample_precision`) things will get slightly easier. But then the following `CHECK` constraint would be needed for integrity:

```
CHECK (date_trunc(sample_precision::text, sample_date)::date = sample_date)
```

(More on improving this further, later.)

**3. Possible range**

You can store a possible range of dates. With either a `possible_start` and `possible_end` or with PostgreSQL's [`daterange` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html).

```
create table t(
  possible_start date,
  possible_end   date,
  -- or
  possible_range daterange
)
```

A month of `2017-03` could be represented with `('2017-03-01', '2017-03-31')`.

In this model when `possible_start = possible_end` then the `date` value is exact. You could query two different things now:

- Which rows happening around given date(s) for sure (*contains*)
- Which rows possibly happening around given date(s) (*intersects*)

Both of these types of queries can use indexes with `daterange`.

The beauty of this is that you are not limited to month ranges. You can use literally any length of ranges. Its only drawback is that the range must be contiguous.

**2. + 3. ?**

There is a variant, which has all of **3.**'s advantages, but looks like **2.** with the [`interval` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html):

```
create table t(
  possible_start  date,
  possible_length interval day
)
```

A month of `2017-03` could be represented with `('2017-03-01', '1 month')`.

(The `day` qualifier restricts the minimum precision of the `interval` to be a day. It is not required for `timestamp` or `timestamptz` based solutions.)

The last possible date could be represented with `(possible_start + possible_length - interval '1 day')::date`. Or, the whole range as (for a `daterange` index): `daterange(possible_start, (possible_start + possible_length)::date)` (ranges are implicitly exclusive on their end).

http://rextester.com/AWIO2403

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I learned a lot whilst trying to understand each of your offered solutions. Because I don't need to index the date and only the day can ever possibly be missing I'll use the first option and store the values separately. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

you can store a date in one column and precision in other, to compare values, you can use `date_trunc(precision_column,DATE)`, eg:

```
t=# create table so36(d date,p text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so36 select now(),'day';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so36 select '2017-03-01','month';
INSERT 0 1
t=# select *,date_trunc(p,d),date_trunc(p,now()) from so36;
     d      |   p   |       date_trunc       |       date_trunc
------------+-------+------------------------+------------------------
 2017-03-28 | day   | 2017-03-28 00:00:00+00 | 2017-03-28 00:00:00+00
 2017-03-01 | month | 2017-03-01 00:00:00+00 | 2017-03-01 00:00:00+00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for offering this solution, I hadn't come across date_trunc before